# programmatic RelativeLayout (similar to CSS float right)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a pretty simple layout - an image on the right with text on the left.  The text should wrap and not overlap the image.  Both are centered vertically to the final height of the container.

RelativeLayout looked appropriate, aligning the image to the parent's right edge, and the textview's right edge with the image's left edge.  The docs make it sound like RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF should do this.

Here's what I have.  The text overlays the image.  I need the textview to be only as large as the available space.

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

ImageView logo = new ImageView(context);
logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.whatever);
logo.setId(0);
addView(logo, lp);

lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, 0);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

TextView header = new TextView(context);
header.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.");
addView(header, lp);
```

I'd very much prefer to do this programmatically (as opposed to XML), for reasons too long and uninteresting to mention.

Any insight would be appreciated.  TYIA.

Comment: don't set your logoId to 0 setId(1231231) something like that and do it like `lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, logo.getId());` you can also setMargins(...) if you need them

Comment: @SergeyBenner ha - i can't believe that worked - if you want to post this comment as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: I've set it as  an answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set your logoId to 0. 
Use `setId(1231231)` instead or ID number something like that and do it like 
`lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, logo.getId());` you can also use `setMargins(...)` if you need them.

---

Cheers